# Pi Pico Micropython Loop seems to get stuck

Tags: gps, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using a Pico as part of my dissertation along with an Arduino Due for a low cost fully autonomous UAV.
Anyway to the point, the code was working before I added the GPS part but now even if I take it out the ultrasonics won't work correctly. only shows the left sensor and doesn't continue on to the GPS.

I was also trying to use the multithreader with no joy :(

Any help or suggestions would be great.

Its a bit messy I know not quite got round to polishing it.

```
    from machine import Pin
import utime, _thread, machine
import os
from rp2 import PIO, StateMachine, asm_pio
#print sys info
print(os.uname())
led_onboard = machine.Pin(25, machine.Pin.OUT)
led_onboard.value(0)     # onboard LED OFF for 0.5 sec
utime.sleep(0.5)
led_onboard.value(1)
uart = machine.UART(0, baudrate=9600)
ser = machine.UART(1, baudrate=9600)
print(uart)
print(ser)

baton = _thread.allocate_lock()

rcvChar = b""

trigger = Pin(3, Pin.OUT) #left 
echo = Pin(2, Pin.IN)

trigger2 = Pin(6, Pin.OUT) #right 
echo2 = Pin(7, Pin.IN)

trigger4 = Pin(9, Pin.OUT) #backward
echo4 = Pin(8, Pin.IN)


def decode(coord):
    #Converts DDDMM.MMMMM > DD deg MM.MMMMM min
    x = coord.split(".")
    head = x[0]
    tail = x[1]
    deg = head[0:-2]
    min = head[-2:]
    return deg + " deg " + min + "." + tail + " min"

def ultraleft():
   trigger.low()
   utime.sleep_us(2)
   trigger.high()
   utime.sleep_us(5)
   trigger.low()
   while echo.value() == 0:
       signaloff = utime.ticks_us()
   while echo.value() == 1:
       signalon = utime.ticks_us()
   timepassed = signalon - signaloff
   Ldistance = (timepassed * 0.0343) / 2  
   utime.sleep(0.1)  
   trigger.low()
   utime.sleep_us(2)
   trigger.high()
   utime.sleep_us(5)
   trigger.low()
   while echo.value() == 0:
       signaloff = utime.ticks_us()
   while echo.value() == 1:
       signalon = utime.ticks_us()
   timepassed = signalon - signaloff
   Ldistance2 = (timepassed * 0.0343) / 2   
   newLdist =  (Ldistance + Ldistance2) / 2
   if newLdist > 120:
       newLdist = 120
   elif newLdist <= 100:
       print("Distance Left less than 100")
       return True
   print("The distance Left from object is ",newLdist,"cm")
   

def ultraright():
   trigger2.low()
   utime.sleep_us(2)
   trigger2.high()
   utime.sleep_us(5)
   trigger2.low()
   while echo2.value() == 0:
       signaloff2 = utime.ticks_us()
   while echo2.value() == 1:
       signalon2 = utime.ticks_us()
   timepassed2 = signalon2 - signaloff2
   Rdistance = (timepassed2 * 0.0343) / 2   
   utime.sleep(0.1)  
   trigger2.low()
   utime.sleep_us(2)
   trigger2.high()
   utime.sleep_us(5)
   trigger2.low()
   while echo2.value() == 0:
       signaloff2 = utime.ticks_us()
   while echo2.value() == 1:
       signalon2 = utime.ticks_us()
   timepassed2 = signalon2 - signaloff2
   Rdistance2 = (timepassed2 * 0.0343) / 2
   newRdist =  (Rdistance + Rdistance2) / 2
   if newRdist > 120:
       newRdist = 120
   elif newRdist <= 100:
       print("Distance Right less than 100")
       return True
   print("The distance Right from object is ",newRdist,"cm")
   
   
   
def ultradwn():
   trigger4.low()
   utime.sleep_us(2)
   trigger4.high()
   utime.sleep_us(5)
   trigger4.low()
   while echo4.value() == 0:
       signaloff4 = utime.ticks_us()
   while echo4.value() == 1:
       signalon4 = utime.ticks_us()
   timepassed4 = signalon4 - signaloff4
   Ddistance = (timepassed4 * 0.0343) / 2
   utime.sleep(0.1)   
   trigger4.low()
   utime.sleep_us(2)
   trigger4.high()
   utime.sleep_us(5)
   trigger4.low()
   while echo4.value() == 0:
       signaloff4 = utime.ticks_us()
   while echo4.value() == 1:
       signalon4 = utime.ticks_us()
   timepassed4 = signalon4 - signaloff4
   Ddistance2 = (timepassed4 * 0.0343) / 2
   newDdist =  (Ddistance + Ddistance2) / 2
   if newDdist > 120:
       newDdist = 120
   elif newDdist >20 :
       print("Distance Down is greater than 20")
       x = 1
       #uart.write("D20")
       #uart.write("\n")
       #print("Sent TO Height")
       return True
   elif newDdist <12 :
       print("Distance Down is less than 12")
       x = 2
       #uart.write("D12")
       #uart.write("\n")
       #print("Sent Landed")
       return True
   print("The distance Down from object is ",newDdist,"cm")
   

def gps():
    while True:
        #baton.acquire()
        rcvChar = ser.readline()
        gps_data =rcvChar.decode("ASCII")
        data = gps_data
        if (data[0:6] == "$GPRMC"):
            sdata = data.split(",")
            if (sdata[2] == 'V'):
                print("no satellite data available")   
            print ("---Parsing GPRMC---")
            time = sdata[1][0:2] + ":" + sdata[1][2:4] + ":" + sdata[1][4:6]
            lat = decode(sdata[3]) #latitude
            dirLat = sdata[4]      #latitude direction N/S
            lon = decode(sdata[5]) #longitute
            dirLon = sdata[6]      #longitude direction E/W
            speed = sdata[7]       #Speed in knots
            trCourse = sdata[8]    #True course
            date = sdata[9][0:2] + "/" + sdata[9][2:4] + "/" + sdata[9][4:6]#date
            print ("time : %s, latitude : %s(%s), longitude : %s(%s), speed : %s, True Course : %s, Date : %s" %  (time,lat,dirLat,lon,dirLon,speed,trCourse,date))
        #baton.acquire()
#_thread.start_new_thread(gps(), ())  

while True:
   x = 0
   #baton.acquire()
   ultraleft()
   utime.sleep(0.1)
   ultraright()
   utime.sleep(0.1)
   ultradwn()
   utime.sleep(0.1)
   if ultraleft():
    uart.write("LO")
    uart.write("\n")
    print("Sent Left")
    utime.sleep(1)
   if ultraright():
    uart.write("RO")
    uart.write("\n")
    print("Sent Right")
    uart.sendbreak()
    utime.sleep(1)
   if ultradwn():
    if x == 1:
        uart.write("D20")
        uart.write("\n")
        print("Sent TO Height")
        utime.sleep(1)
    if x == 2:
        uart.write("D12")
        uart.write("\n")
        print("Sent Landed")
        utime.sleep(1)
    utime.sleep(1)
    gps()
    #baton.release()
```

Comment: There are a number of things you could do to make it easier to fix this. 1) turn all those ultra funcs into one func that takes the trigger and echo as an argument. 2) print information before and after those while loops. Chances are, one of those while loops are running forever. 3) fix all your formatting issues. You have a big mess and instead of fixing the mess you are trying to make the mess work. It takes about 1/4 of the code (or less) to express the exact same logic. Fixing 50 lines of code is much easier than fixing 200 lines.

Comment: @MichaelGuidry Thank you for your help, I have implemented your suggestions and it works perfectly. I will learn from this and try to not over-complicated something quite simple/

Comment: Glad I could help, Nathaniel. It doesn't work perfectly, though. It just works. You'll eventually learn more, possibly revisit this code, and realize numerous places it could be improved. It's all part of being good at anything. Time and effort.